# How to stop update original map when I add new map in QGIS3.26 layout

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, print-composer

I want to create a map with multiple map to show different layers like this:

[image]

And in the map1, I checked the "**Lock layers**" and "**Lock styles for layer**" option

[image]

But when I just use mouse wheel to adjust whole page scale (not in "**Move item content**" function),  the map1 display layer has been changed to map2:

[image]

How can I stop it update the map1 display layer?

Comment: Your page scale does not seem to change. Maybe if you only scroll the mouse wheel with the Map1 item not selected at all (it is selected as per your screenshot)